# current branch のみに所属する revesions のみを git rebase -i したい

Tags: git

```
  * (rev1, HEAD, BranchA)
  |
  * (rev2)
  |
* / (rev3, BranchB)
|/
*   (rev4)
|
*   (rev5)
```

の状況で、rev2 の SHA-1 を指定せずに (rev1, rev2) のみを対象とする git rebase -i をしたいのですが、そのようなオプションは存在するのでしょうか

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to get the changes on a branch in git
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53569/how-to-get-the-changes-on-a-branch-in-git

```
git log BranchA --not BranchB
git log BranchB..BranchA
```

といった表記で実現できるようです